# JSON Image parsing in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I've tried to parse JSON from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos
Everything works great, but instead of getting a picture I get only text with the URL of this particular picture.
Here is my code. What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance!
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var posts = [Post]()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{List(posts, id: \.albumId) { post in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(post: post)) {
                
                HStack() {
                    Text(String(describing: post.albumId))
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                
            }.navigationBarTitle("Albums")
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(post.title)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(post.url)
        }
    }
}


struct Post: Decodable {
    var albumId: Int
    var title: String
    var url: String
}


extension ContentView
{
    func loadData() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos") else {
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                if let response_obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data) {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.posts = response_obj
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're just passing those properties into...`Text()`, so that's all you'll get. I don't know SwiftUI to know wha you _do_ need t do, but can I intuit that if you call `Text()`, you'll get text.

Comment: I mean, what did you expect - you're only outputing `Text(post.url)`, and `url` is a String. First, change `url` to be `URL` and then you'd need to load the image asynchronously from the url. Here's a blog that you might find useful: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

```
var body: some View {
    WebImage(url: URL(string: "http://...."))
}
```